# Minecraft Importing sounds to 1.9 Resouce Packs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What's the ogg file name and where do i need to place it the sound for punch sound in Minecraft 1.9 resource pack!?

Answer (score 2):

This is only for 1.9... older versions have a different structure.

Location:
`assets/minecraft/sounds/entity/player/attack/` (if it doesn't exist - create it)

Files to (re)place:

1. weak1.ogg - weak4.ogg
2. strong1.ogg - strong6.ogg